# sftp inbound channel adapter not picking modified file with same name

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

I am using sftp adapter with composite filter(SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter) which is being backed by PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore. Now as far as I know this filter check last modified timestamp of the file and based on that it filters the file.

Even though I use this filter and drop updated file, it is not picking up that new file.

Note : download file locally saved to some temp dir. No local filter being used. We always going to have same file name. Only thing changes everyday is content and file timestamp.

Here is my composite filter config

```
<bean id="compositeFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
<constructor-arg>
    <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter">
            <constructor-arg value="test.txt" />
        </bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">
            <constructor-arg name="store" ref="metadataStore"/>
            <constructor-arg value="myapp"/>
        </bean>
    </list>
</constructor-arg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `local-filter` is an `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`. If you don't remove the file after processing, you can't use an `AcceptAllFileListFilter`, you will need a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` in the local filter.

But, generally, it's better to remove or rename the file after processing and use the accept all filter.

Comment: I am trying to move file to diff dir but some how I am getting IO exception "java.io.IOException: Failed to delete original file". I am doing this in step listener after step where I know my job is completed and we have only one step. Looks like file is locked by some other process during processing. Here is the flow. Poll file, launch job with filename, after file is processed remove from original folder to processed folder.

Comment: After moving my file moving code to job listener from step listener, it started working. Thank you very much Gary for your help

Comment: I think i spoke too early about the fix. Even if I am now moving file to diff folder, it is now downloading file locally but not invoking job with file which has diff timestamp. Again, no local filter used only composite filter as per described in original problem desc. Only thing added is moving file once it is processed to diff dir.

Comment: As I said "no local-filter" means `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` locally.

Comment: After using AccpetAllFileListFilter locally, issue got resolved. Thank you